# matlab warning conflict name

Tags: matlab

```
% Name of the excel file

filename = 'directory\output.xls';

% Name of the sheet you wan to delete

sname='corner';

% Open Excel as a COM Automation server

Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');

% Open Excel workbook

Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);

%get a handle to the sheet

hsheet=Excel.Sheets.Item(sname);

hsheet.Delete

% Now save/close/quit/delete

Workbook.Save;

Excel.Workbook.Close;

invoke(Excel, 'Quit');

delete(Excel)
```

Above is the code which work on other filename but not the file i wish to delete...why? The warning as below:

> `Warning: Function directory\norm.m
>   has the same name as a MATLAB builtin.
>   We suggest you rename the function to
>   avoid a potential name conflict.`

However, the norm.m is not a function, is the script and the result of the norm.m will be the output.xls...how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Matlab function called `norm` that comes with Matlab. If you rename your file to something else, it will stop complaining. On the other hand, this shouldn't brake your program either. It should still work, even with that warning. It has nothing to do with the file you're trying to delete.

Comment: i didnt use norm function inside my norm.m script...mean that i need to rename the norm.m to something like normal.m?

Comment: Yes. Matlab is telling you that it's not sure which `norm` you mean when you call it.

Comment: That's what I wrote in the answer. This warning has nothing to do with why it wouldn't work. The question now is *how* doesn't it work? What exactly happens when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`which`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/which.html;jsessionid=476BTV2YvlkhJFL5kWRf283QnZmttWVpPcvPgsTTTSZThQXBrGvW!-287992931) command to locate the file that is called `norm.m`. This command should list both the built-in commands and any other m-file (function or scripts) that is on the [MATLAB Search Path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/br5tea6-6.html).

If you found that you have made a `norm.m` file which you can't rename because it has been used in many places inside your source code, you will need to `grep` your source code to rename those. Otherwise, there is no guarantee whether your version or MATLAB's version will be called.

---

The following is quoted directly from MATLAB's [online docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/br5tea6-6.html):

> **Detecting and Addressing Name Conflicts**
>
> MATLAB might not be
>   accessing the file that you want it to
>   when:
>
> - You use a file and get a warning about a potential name conflict.
> - You get unexpected results.
>
> To identify a name conflict, try using the `which` function.
>
> To address a name conflict, try one of the following:
>
> - Change the current folder.
> - Move or remove folders on the search path.
> - Rename or move files.
> - Specify the full path or partial path to the file that you want.
> - Maintain a single version of a file instead of multiple versions.
>
> Name conflicts can arise from using files that you create. Conflicts also can arise from using:
>
> - Files that others create, such as from File Exchange
> - A different system that has additional MathWorks products installed
> - A different version of MATLAB, which could include new functions that have the same names as your existing files